# Use fetched result to select columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python script which connects to a SQL database and retrieves the values within a column.
How do I go about printing these specific columns from my dataframe rather than explicitly typing it?

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select [FIELDS] from dbo.CONFIG WHERE [DESTINATION] = 'remote'")
cols = [x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]
print(cols)
```

**Output:**

```
cols = ['_id, connId, locationName']
```

**Print Statement for Dataframe:**

```
df = df[cols]
print(df)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Dave/Documents/testing.py", line 35, in <module>
    root = root[cols]
  File "c:\Users\Dave\Documents\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3030, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "c:\Users\Dave\Documents\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1265, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "c:\Users\Dave\Documents\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1307, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['_id, connId, locationName'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I want to select these specific columns from my dataframe but its taking the entire list as one string so its giving me the error string:`None of [Index['_id, connId, locationName'] are in the [columns]`.

So the list needs to be in this sort of format so that its getting each column rather than taking the entire list as a string:

```
cols = ["_id", "connId", "locationName"]
```

**End Result:**

```
df = df[cols]
print(df)

_id  connId   locationName
23   423434       Scotland
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select first value and split by `,`:

```
cols = ['_id, connId, locationName']
df = df[cols[0].split(', ')]
```

Or:

```
cols = [x[0].split(', ') for x in cursor.fetchall()]
df = df[cols[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try a list comprehension

```
[trg.strip() for col in df.columns for trg in col.split(',')]
['_id', 'connId', 'locationName']
```